# Pandoc Latex to word References

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

The conversion from Latex (tex file prepared using elsarticle class) to word (docx) using pandoc is working fine however I am not getting the references at all (not within the text neither at the end of the article). I used the following code and had an error of "pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xa8': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream".

`pandoc --citeproc input.tex --bibliography=mybiblio.bib --csl=ieee.csl -o document.docx`

I am using latest version of pandoc (fresh installation two days ago). The `.tex` file is working fine in terms of formatting and references. Tried the following steps found by searching but they did not work;

Using `filter=pandoc-citeproc` in pandoc it asks me to use `--citeproc`

If I omit `--citeproc` in my coding, I do not get the error (also dont get the references as well).

`Jabref` coding is already set to UTF.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954642/pandoc-complains-about-utf-8-decoding-error-even-if-my-file-is-valid-utf-8-encod

Comment: Could you please write how can I use this command according to my example? I am not from this field.. I wrote:

````iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c input.tex````

And I had the following error,

'iconv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

````pandoc iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c input.tex````

gave me the error of "unknown extension: 8"

Comment: @Jack - You are on windows? You might need to install `iconv` first: Try `cygwin` or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm). Another way would be with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) "Encoding > Convert to UTF-8". Also, it looks like you need to recode your .bib-file

Comment: I followed the method of using Notepad++ as per your suggestion and it is working fine. Thanks! @DG'

Comment: `pandoc -f markdown-raw_tex --citeproc input.tex --bibliography=mybiblio.bib --csl=ieee.csl -o document.docx`, I would imagine

Comment: This coding put the whole text of the Latex file (including Latex coding,comments) into a docx output file. It is like copying all of the Latex coding from my .tex file into a word document. @homocomputeris

Comment: If other people look at this, the solution would be `pandoc -f latex --citeproc input.tex --bibliography=mybiblio.bib --csl=ieee.csl -o document.docx` - substitute the argument after `-f` with your filetype (a latex file in @Jack's case). you may need to change the .csl to match what you have in your wd too. Find the file options here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--from